# How to run a non-brew app on startup in OS X Sierra

Tags: macos, elasticsearch

I had to install an older version of Elasticsearch (2.3.3) from source.  The binary is located in `/opt/local/elasticsearch-2.3.3/bin/` I created the following file

**/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.elasticsearch.plist**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>org.elasticsearch</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/opt/local/elasticsearch-2.3.3/bin/elasticsearch</string>
        </array>
        <key>UserName</key>
        <string>root</string>
<!--         <key>GroupName</key>
        <string>staff</string> -->
        <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
        <string>/opt/local/elasticsearch-2.3.3/bin</string>
        <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <true/>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

I then issue the following command:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.elasticsearch.plist
```

When I inquire with `sudo launchctl list | grep elastic` it returns `org.elasticsearch`.  But when I check if elasticsearch is running with `ps ax | grep elastic` it is not running.

Is there something wrong with my `.plist` file?

Comment: Is the web interface responding(by default I believe it should be: `http://localhost:9200`) ?

Comment: curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused

Answer (score 0):

> Is there something wrong with my .plist file?

It lacks of `<key>Program</key>` at least so there's nothing to be run for it at all.

Since it's Apple specific question you'd better use https://apple.stackexchange.com/